# Chain rule for multivariable differentiation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, chain-rule

For one-dimensional case, after affine transformation 
\begin{equation}
x=\hat{x}+\sigma c .
\end{equation}
Using the chain rule for differentiation, we can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dc}=\frac{dx}{dc}\frac{d}{dx}=\sigma\frac{d}{dx}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dc}\bigg(\frac{d}{dc}\bigg)&=\frac{d}{dc}\bigg(\sigma\frac{d}{dx}\bigg)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dc^2}&=\sigma\frac{d}{dc}\bigg(\frac{d}{dx}\bigg)\\&
=\sigma \frac{dx}{dc}\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{d}{dx}\bigg)
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{dc^2}=\sigma^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}.
\end{equation}
For multi-dimensional case, 
\begin{equation}
x=\hat{x}+D c,
\end{equation}
where $x,c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $D$ is any lower traiangular matrix of order $n\times n$. How to use chain rule for differentiation 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial }{\partial c_i}=\text{constant1} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial c_i^2}=\text{constant2} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i}^{n}  \frac{\partial ^3}{\partial c_i^2\, \partial c_j} = \text{constant3} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i}^{n}  \frac{\partial ^3}{\partial x_i^2\, \partial x_j}
\end{equation}
and what will be the values of these constants.

Comment: A lot of your equations seem to have left out $x$.  And if might be easier if you explained what $\hat x$ means, and how it relates to $x$

Comment: Here $x\sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{x},P)$, and $P=DD^T$, actually here $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is expectation of $x$, which will be any constant.

Comment: Hint: The differential of a linear transformation is the transformation itself. An affine transformation is the composition of a linear transformation and a translation.